# proof from Introduction to Statistical Learning: error term in linear model

Tags: statistics

In Introduction to Statistical Learning there is a statement in chapter 2 that explains why there is an error term in a linear model.

they write "it is easy to show that $E(Y − \hat{Y} )
^2 = E[f(X) + \epsilon − \hat{f}(X)]^2
= [f(X) − \hat{f}(X)]^2
+ Var(\epsilon)$

I'm not finding it easy to show. Can someone offer the proof?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3228607/321264

Answer (score 0):

$$E\left[(Y-\hat Y)^2\right]=E\left[\left(f(X)+\epsilon-\hat{f}(X)\right)^2\right]\\
=E\left[\left(f(X)+\epsilon-\hat{f}(X)\right)\left(f(X)+\epsilon-\hat{f}(X)\right)\right]=E\left[\left(f(X)-\hat{f}(X)\right)^2+2\epsilon\left(f(X)-\hat{f}(X)\right)+\epsilon^2\right]\\
=E\left[\left(f(X)-\hat{f}(X)\right)^2\right]+E\left[\epsilon^2\right]+2E\left[\epsilon\left(f(X)-\hat{f}(X)\right)\right]$$

Because $f$ and $\hat{f}$ are constant
$$
=\left[f(X)-\hat{f}(X)\right]^2
   +E\left[\epsilon^2\right]+2E\left[\epsilon\left(f(X)-\hat{f}(X)\right)\right] \\
$$
Since the mean of $\epsilon$ is zero
$$
 =\left[f(X)-\hat{f}(X)\right]^2
   +E\left[\epsilon^2\right]
=\left[f(X)-\hat{f}(X)\right]^2 + Var(\epsilon)$$