# expected value for $(f(X) + \epsilon - \hat{f}(X))^2$

Tags: statistics

$\newcommand{\E}{\mathbb{E}}\newcommand{\Var}{\operatorname{Var}}$In *An Introduction To Statistical Learning page 19*, it states

> Consider a given estimate $\hat f$ and a set of predictors $X$, which yields the predicition $\hat Y = \hat f(X)$. Assume for a mement that both $\hat f$ and $X$ are fixed. Then it is easy to show that

\begin{align}
\E[(Y - \hat Y)^2] =& \E[(f(X) + \epsilon - \hat f(X))^2]
\\
=& (f(X) - \hat f(X))^2 + \Var(\epsilon)
\end{align}

> Where $\E(Y - \hat Y)$ represents the average, or *expected value*, of the squared difference between the predicted and actual value of $Y$, and $\Var(\epsilon)$ represents the *variance*  associated with the error term $\epsilon$.

My question is, how is this derived? I can only get so far.

\begin{align}
\E[f(X) + \epsilon - \hat f(X)]^2 
=& 
\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N \left( f(X_i) + \epsilon - \hat  f(X_i) \right)^2
\\
=& 
\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N \left( f^2 - 2f \hat f + \hat f^2 + \epsilon^2  + 2\epsilon f - 2 \epsilon \hat  f \right)^2
\\
=& 
\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N \left( (f - \hat f)^2 + \epsilon^2  + 2\epsilon f - 2 \epsilon \hat  f \right)^2
\end{align}

I am not sure how $\Var(\epsilon)$ term is derived.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key fact that allows you to derive that equation is that on page 16 it is stated that $\epsilon$ has "zero mean" and is independent of X, along with the assumption that both $X$ and $\hat{f}$ are fixed. To really understand the derivation, you have to understand the probabilistic concept of "expectation". The expectation is denoted $E[ ]$ or $\mathbb{E}[]$ in most places. Expectation, or the "mean", is sometimes called "average" but it isn't quite the same thing as "summing things up and dividing by the number of things" that we learn in grade school. The average you learn when you're young is known as the "sample average" in probability. The concepts are related, of course, but you don't have to dwell on that at this point.  I'd recommend reading Chapter 3 of https://www.deeplearningbook.org/contents/prob.html, and maybe section 1.2 of this book https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/uploads/prod/2006/01/Bishop-Pattern-Recognition-and-Machine-Learning-2006.pdf, and then maybe coming back to this answer. You should look at chapter 2 of that second book later...

Expanding the argument to the expectation gives
$$E[(f(X)+\epsilon-\hat{f}(x))^2] = E[ (f(X) -\hat{f}(X))^2+2\epsilon(f(X)-\hat{f}(X))+\epsilon^2]$$ 
Applying "linearity of expectation" gives:
 $$E[ (f(X) -\hat{f}(X))^2+2\epsilon(f(X)-\hat{f}(X))+\epsilon^2] = E[ (f(X) -\hat{f}(X))^2] +E[2\epsilon(f(X)-\hat{f}(X))]+E[\epsilon^2]$$

Since $X$ and $\hat{f}$ are assumed to be fixed and "independent" of $\epsilon$, $E()$ pretty much treats them like a constant. That means that:
$$E[ (f(X) -\hat{f}(X))^2] = (f(X) -\hat{f}(X))^2$$
and
$$E[2\epsilon(f(X)-\hat{f}(X))] = E(\epsilon)2(f(X)-\hat{f}(X)).$$ The second thing applies linearity of expectation, again.

The assumption that $\epsilon$ has zero mean, means that $E(\epsilon)$ equals zero.

The definition of variance is:
$$
\text{var}[\epsilon] = E(\epsilon^2) - (E(\epsilon))^2
$$ but since $E(\epsilon) = 0$, that means $\text{var}(\epsilon) = E(\epsilon^2)$.

This is confusing if you don't know probability or haven't seen it in a long time. The notation of the book really doesn't help- it's kind of sloppy imo. If you read that chapter, you'll note that really we shouldn't be talking about "expectation" but "conditional expectation", and we should be writing $E( \text{whatever} | X)$ instead of $E(\text{whatever})$. Regardless, you'll be able to get the gist.

Comment: Great explanation, much appreciated. I agree the notation doesn't help in the book.

Answer (score 1):

"Assume for a moment that both $\hat{f}$ and $X$ are fixed."

Then the only random quantity in $(Y - \hat{Y})^2$ is $Y$.

I presume $Y = f(X) + \epsilon$ and that $E[\epsilon] = 0$ despite you not mentioning this.
Substituting this and $\hat{f}(X) = \hat{Y}$ yields
$$E[(Y - \hat{Y})^2] = E[(f(X) + \epsilon - \hat{f}(X))^2].$$

The quantity inside the square brackets can be written as
$$(f(X) - \hat{f}(X))^2 + 2 \epsilon (f(X) - \hat{f}(X)) + \epsilon^2.$$
The first term is non-random by assumption so its expectation is itself. The second term has expectation $E[2 \epsilon (f(X) - \hat{f}(X))] = 2 (f(X) - \hat{f}(X)) E[\epsilon] = 0$. The last term has expectation $E[\epsilon^2] = \text{Var}(\epsilon)$.

Comment: You are correct that $E(\epsilon) = 0$